# Variable increment based on a check box being checked or not in PHP

Tags: php, checkbox

I have got two requirements for the code snippet below.

- The `var` is to be incremented when I click the check box. - **Done**
- The `var` should save the previous number if the check box is not
  checked. - **Not Done**

Currently it changes back to 1 if you do not check the check box for var.

The code snippet:

```
if (isset($_POST['var'])) { 
    $var = $var + 1; 
} else { 
    $var = $_POST['var']; 
}
```

Comment: Can you use 'hidden' for that?

Comment: Your if-else statement is not logical. You're saying that if the POST variable var exists, then increment $var, but if it does not exist, set $var equal to a variable that does not exist. What is this "previous number" you mention? Is that $var?

Comment: yes the previous number is var.

Comment: this is just the way I have tried. But I am open to anyone that knows how to increment a varaible based on if a checkbox is checked or not. If the checkbox wasn't checked I would like whatever number was variable. Ex if you incremted the variable 3 times but not the fourth i would want it to save 3.

Comment: When you say "save" the previous number, what do you mean by that? Save it in the variable, or save it in a session variable, or save it in a database, or save it in a file?

Comment: the count starts at 0. so if i don't check the var  checkbox, i want it to display 0. if i did check the var check box i want the 'var' to be 1. etc. In this case 0 is the previous number. Basically whatever number is in var before the form was saved.

Comment: i want a counter that counts how many times a checkbox has been checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using session variables for your purpose.

Firstly, you may start the new session like this:

```
session_start();
```

Then, you could do the thing you desire in the following manner:

```
// Initialize $_SESSION['var'], if needed
if(!isset($_SESSION['var'])) {

    $_SESSION['var'] = 0;   

}

if (isset($_POST['var'])) {

    // Increment the var
    $var = $_SESSION['var'] + 1; 

    // Save the var as a session variable
    $_SESSION['var'] = $var;

} else { 

    // Restore the var from the session variable
    $var = $_SESSION['var']; 

}
```

Also, at some point you might want to destroy a session data. It is performed as following in PHP:

```
session_destroy();
```

Please take into account the fact that good practices of using PHP sessions is a completely separate question for which you could google.

[Click for some more sandbox-level info on PHP Sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_sessions.asp).

UPD: Here is a full PHP / HTML code for a working example of what you are looking for:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            Increment $var <input type="checkbox" name="var" value="var">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <p>
            <?php

            // Initialize $_SESSION['var'], if needed
            if(!isset($_SESSION['var'])) {
                $_SESSION['var'] = 0;       
            }

            if (isset($_POST['var'])) {
                // Increment the var
                $var = $_SESSION['var'] + 1; 
                // Save the var as a session variable
                $_SESSION['var'] = $var;
            } else { 
                // Restore the var from the session variable
                $var = $_SESSION['var']; 
            }

            echo $var;

            ?>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please let me know whether it helps or not.

Comment: No sorry, same as before.

Comment: @user3416665, I have found a mistake in my solution, and now it is updated. Please try if it works.

Comment: now its incrementing no matter if you $var is selected or not. I appreciate the help tho!

Comment: @user3416665, one more update. It works totally fine in my testing environment. Please check it, if it still does not work, I would post the whole .php file I used for testing.

Comment: still not working :( just increments not matter what

Comment: can you post you .php file it would be really appreicated

Comment: Dear @user3416665, I have updated the post with the full code for you!

Comment: your code definitely works it must be something with mine :S. Thanks so much for your help tho. really appreciate it!